# Is there a way to select different things depending on the value of a specific cell?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I've been trying to figure this out for days but nothing helped me.
Basically, I want to use the SELECT keyword to query different values, depending on the value of a cell. Here's an example to help clarify things:

Imagine I have a table T with 3 columns: A, B and C.
I want to be able to do

```sql
SELECT A FROM T
```

if C on that row holds a value of 1. If C, on that row, holds a value of 2, however, I want to be able to do

```sql
SELECT B FROM T
```

,

I'm using the sqlite3 module for python, so I'm looking for a single expression that could do what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE` expression:

```
CASE WHEN T.c=1 THEN T.a WHEN T.c=2 THEN T.b END
```

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use CASE to do this, like,

```
SELECT CASE C WHEN 1 THEN A ELSE B END FROM T WHERE C IN (1,2);
```